# ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Here the structure of my project(debug_project) folder.

[image]

This is my Docker compose command.

[image]

After executing the command, I get this error.

[image]

Here is my docker-compose-dev.yml file.

[image]

[This](https://blog.docker.com/2017/05/spring-boot-development-docker/) is the link I have followed.

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2):

It is assumed that the Dockerfile is present relative to the folder specified in the context field.

So you have two choices either move the Dockerfile inside the app directory or have an absolute path to the Dockerfile.

Something like

```
foo:
  build:
    context: app
    dockerfile: ${PWD}/Dockerfile-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

The context specifies the path to the directory containing the docker file.  You need to move the Dockerfile-dev into that directory.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build

> Either a path to a directory containing a Dockerfile, or a url to a git repository.
>
> When the value supplied is a relative path, it is interpreted as relative to the location of the Compose file. This directory is also the build context that is sent to the Docker daemon.